# Android with multiple content view at same time?

Tags: android, menu, android-activity, android-intent

I'm very new to android and I am wondering how I can have 2 windows displaying content at the same time.

Here is an example:
I have a HorizontalScrollView at the bottom of the screen which houses the buttons for a menu. Above it, I would like a window(like a JFrame) that I can change depending on which button from the menu was pressed. The ScrollView menu must remain unchanged an exist as a separate entity(if you know what I mean).

How can I go about doing this? I don't want to have to draw the menu every time a user click a button and a new page is displayed. I have a feeling it has something to do with intents and Activities, but I'm not sure.

Hope someone can help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm very new to android and I am wondering how I can have 2 windows displaying content at the same time.

Interpreting you literally, you can't, but that's because "window" does not mean what you think it does.

> Here is an example: I have a HorizontalScrollView at the bottom of the screen which houses the buttons for a menu.

Get rid of it and replace it with an options menu, so your application blends in with the platform.

> Above it, I would like a window(like a JFrame) that I can change depending on which button from the menu was pressed. The ScrollView menu must remain unchanged an exist as a separate entity(if you know what I mean). How can I go about doing this?

Option #1: Get rid of the `HorizontalScrollView`, use an options menu, and use separate activities for each "window"

Option #2: Use a `ViewFlipper`, with one child of the `ViewFlipper` for each "window".

Of the two, Option #1 will generally be much better, for memory management, state management, code complexity, and UI design.

Comment: So, by pressing the Menu button on the android phone, a menu will pop up for the user to access and change views? I don't have an android phone so I can't test it :) 

Thanks for all the help everyone.

Comment: Rich, you can test your menu out on the emulator.

Comment: Yeah, I've managed to get the menu to work now... But it's a crap! Android seems to be very limited. Hopefully it will improve with time.

Answer (score 0):

Could TabLayout be your answer :

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: That could be one method, however, it's not ideal. I have about 8 menu items and they are housed in the HorizonltalScrollVie, which allows users to scroll through the menu items. I want a permanent scrollable menu with a separate place on the screen for displaying content.